# Adding an ID to div class item breaks the navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu where I translate the menu-items based on the chosen language. While the code works for the dropdown (sub-)menu items (by querying their IDs), I get an error message as soon as I add an ID to the dropdown menu and the menu messes up.

Working code:

```
    <div class="main_nav_menu">
        <a href="..." class="menu-item" id="item_home">Home</a>
        
        <div class="menu-item grp">Grouped Item<span class="arrow"> ▼</span>
            <div class="nav_submenu">
                <a href="..." class="submenu-item" id="item_1">Item 1</a>
                <a href="..." class="submenu-item" id="item_2">Item 2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <a href="..." class="menu-item" id="item_contact">Contact</a>
    </div>

    // Extract current language parameter from URL
    var currentLang = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get('lang');
    
    // Function to update menu content based on the selected language
    function updateMenuContent(selectedLang) {
        switch (selectedLang) {
            case 'de':
                document.getElementById('item_home').textContent = 'Home';
                document.getElementById('item_contact').textContent = 'Kontakt';
                ...
            case 'fr':
                document.getElementById('item_home').textContent = 'Home';
                document.getElementById('item_contact').textContent = 'Contact';
                ...
            default:
            // Default case (EN)
        }
    }
```

Issue:

As soon as I change this code:

```
<div class="menu-item grp">Grouped Item<span class="arrow"> ▼</span>
```

to:

```
<div class="menu-item grp" id="item_grp">Grouped Item<span class="arrow"> ▼</span>
```

...and try to translate it with the code line:

```
document.getElementById('item_grp').textContent = 'Gruppierte Einträge';
```

...the whole navigation menu goes rogue and triggers the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')
at updateMenuContent (wordpress/?lang=de:183:66)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (wordpress/?lang=de:232:3)
updateMenuContent @ wordpress/?lang=de:183
(anonymous) @ wordpress/?lang=de:232
```

I tried to use data-translation-keys instead of an ID, but that creates the same issue. It seems like everything works as long as I do not try to translate the menu item which has submenu content. All menu items without submenu work and all submenu items themselves work as well.

It looks like it fetches a null value, but I set the menu item to "Grouped Item"...so how can it be null?

Comment: Maybe fix the formatting on your code in the question.

Comment: Apologize, you replied while I was editing. Took me some time to get it properly formatted. Now it should be easier to read.

Comment: Maybe you missed`<script>your javascript code</script>`

Comment: I have that. I removed some code from the upper section where I describe it, to keep it easier to read. The code works as long as I do not assign IDs to menu items which have submenu items.